# JQuery.append() - How to append without an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, devexpress, devextreme

As I'm trying to create a PhoneJS application that is completely 100% dynamic, I've encountered a problem with the `$().append()`.

Every example I've seen from the JQuery API reference, other SO's and other random articles on the web, ALWAYS seems to append and given element to a specific ID.

Consider the following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="something"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var tmp = $('<div></div>').SomeKindOfElement(WithSomeKindOfContent);

//People always append this to a specific element like so
$('#something').append(tmp);
```

As you see, it's being appended to a specific ID.

Now, what if I didn't know how many elements I needed to add? I could do the following

```
<div id="something1"></div>
<div id="something2"></div>
<div id="something3"></div>
<div id="something4"></div>
<div id="something5"></div>
```

Loop through whatever items I receive, and hoping that no more than 5 elements needs to be added.

Isn't there a way for me to add new elements, without binding them to a specific element in my HTML, but simply create a new `<div>` element?

**ONLY TO THOSE KNOWING DEVEXTREME**

Basically I'm creating a dxChart like so:

```
$('#chart').dxChart({
    dataSource: [
        { 'Product': 'Pie', 'QTY': 25 },
        { 'Product': 'Chocolate Cake', 'QTY': 12 },
        { 'Product': 'Muffins', 'QTY': 78 }
    ],
    series: { name: 'Test', argumentField: 'Product', valueField: 'QTY'},
    commonSeriesSettings: {
        type: 'bar'
    }
});
```

But as you see, I'm binding this chart to a `<div>` element in the markup, that has id of `chart`, like so:

```
<div data-options="dxView : { name: 'graph', title: 'graph' } " >
    <div data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } ">
        <h1 class="headline">Dashboard</h1>
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But again, what if I were to create 2 charts? The first charts would be overridden by the second chart.

Comment: id should be unique, you can append it to a class selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got response from the DevExtreme Support with this answer:**

The http://jsfiddle.net/tm481tew/ example demonstrates how to accomplish this task

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('<div>')
.appendTo('#container')
.dxChart({
    dataSource: [
        { 'Product': 'Pie', 'QTY': 25 },
        { 'Product': 'Chocolate Cake', 'QTY': 12 },
        { 'Product': 'Muffins', 'QTY': 78 }
    ],
    series: { name: 'Test', argumentField: "Product", valueField: "QTY" },
    commonSeriesSettings: {
        type: 'bar'
    }
});
```

**MARKUP**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Its the same as I told you before `$("<div></div>").appendTo(document.body).dxChart({ ... });`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify id, calling `var node = $("<div></div>")` will create new div element and assign it to the `node` variable. Then you can append the node where you want, for instance to body like this: `node.appendTo(document.body)`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I guess I can do `node.appendTo('some-random-id/class')`

Comment: try `var node = $("<div>xxx</div>")`, is there a chance that you just did not realized empty div on page?

Comment: Then it just adds the content `xxx`, but not the actual JQuery object

Comment: I will try it in another way. `$("<div></div>").appendTo(document.body).dxChart({ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

When you create your `tmp` object, it is a jQuery object that is "wrapping" an element (`div` in your case).

This `tmp` object is detached from the DOM when created, and it will not appear in the UI until you inject it to the page using the `.append(...)` function.

In order to inject it to the page, you need to specify "where to" inject it, and you can do it by using any selector you wish, whether it is an `#id`, `.class` or directly to another jQuery object using `tmp.appendTo(existingElement)`

Comment: The strange thing is that if I append this to `<div id="random"></div>` it doesn't show me anything. Like so: `tmp.appendTo('#random')`

Comment: Does this div (#random) exist on the page? or is it another div you created dynamically and still haven't inject it to the page...?

Comment: Exists in on the page

Comment: It's hard to guess what is wrong there... Try to put together a JsFiddle that reproduce your problem, and it will be much easier to help you :-)

Comment: Quite difficult, as I'm using DevExtreme to create a PhoneJS application. I believe this is where the problem lies. I've made a thread on their support forum. Waiting for response. Will report back once I've heard from them